# PHPMailer с localhost сообщения отправляются, с сайта - нет

Tags: email, php, классы, sendmail

Пробовал с gmail, с mail.ru, yander, указывая и не указывая порты, указывая $mail -> SMTPSecure = 'ssl' -- ничего не работает.

```
require("class/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SetLanguage( 'en', 'class/language/' );
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.mail.ru";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "name@mail.ru";
$mail->Password = "Qs564sfsxxx";
$mail->From = "name@mail.ru";
$mail->FromName = "Name";
$mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
$mail->AddReplyTo("name@mail.ru", "Information");
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->IsHTML(true); 
$mail->Subject = "Reg";
$mail->Body    = "Nice to see you, ".$name."!";
$mail->AltBody = "Nice to see you, ".$name."!";

if(!$mail->Send())
{

array_push($_SESSION[error],22);
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;

}else{
$_SESSION[noerror]=1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$mail->AltBody = "Nice to see you, ".$name."!
```

Тут не закрыта кавычка и отсутствует точка с запятой в конце строки.

```
$_SESSION[error]
...
$_SESSION[noerror]
```

Имена ключей массива следует заключать в кавычки